# How we change dependent picklist drop down value to input field value?

Tags: picklist

i have one controlling picklist Type and value is Hourly and Fixed. If i choose hourly then it show value Rate, Hours per week and Duration. And if i choose fixed then it show Prize and Duration As a drop down but  i want these fields as a input field. How it possible?

[image]

Comment: One way to vary the fields that are displayed would be to change type into a record type - see [Displaying Record Types](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_record_types.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I would just get rid of the 'Hourly' and 'Fixed' picklists, and replace them with one picklist 'Way of Charging' or similar, which then contains all 4 values:

- Rate
- Hours per week
- Duration
- Prize

and make those dependent of the 'Type'.

Comment: thanx but i want all fields as editable fields after select in picklist.....all fields are in drop down list but i want as editable field ??

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Could you elaborate on how you would like the system to behave?